# GCP Classic Load Balancer route to external URL

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcp-load-balancer

I have a GCP classic load balancer that is configured to route traffic to a few backends (VMs in Instance Group). I now want a path that routes to my website that is **not on GCP**

**Example**

1. https://gcp-lb.com/backend-1 > VM port 3000
2. https://gcp-lb.com/backend-2 > VM port 5000
3. https://gcp-lb.com/my-website > https://my-external-website.com

For case 3, I did the following

- Create a NEG (network endpoint group)

  - name: my-website-neg
  - type: NEG (internet)
  - FQDN (fully qualified domain name): my-external-website.com
- In the LB, add a Backend service

  - name: `my-website-backend`
  - Backend Type: Internet NEG
  - Protocol: HTTP
  - Backends: select `my-website-neg`
- In the LB, add Host & path rules

  - Hosts: *
  - Paths: `/my-website`, `/my-website/*`
  - Backends: `my-website-backend`

With the above configuration, when I open the URL https://gcp-lb.com/my-website, I get the below error

[image]

Can anyone guide me if this is possible at all and if I'm missing any configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud HTTP(S) load balancers and Traffic Director use a Google Cloud configuration resource called a URL map to route requests to backend services or backend buckets.

For example, with an external HTTP(S) load balancer, you can use a single URL map to route requests to different destinations based on the rules

configured in the URL map:

- Requests for https://example.com/video go to one backend service.
- Requests for https://example.com/audio go to a different backend
  service
- Requests for https://example.com/images go to a Cloud Storage backend
  bucket
- Requests for any other host and path combination go to a default
  backend service

For more information follow this link for [URL maps overview](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/url-map-concepts#advanced-traffic-management)